# print variable name in a #define

Tags: c++, macros, console-application

I am trying to print out to console using a macro the variable name for display members value while debugging ( logging ).
How to do that? I tried the following but it doesnt' work.

```
#define MY_PRINT(x) std::cout << "'x'=" << x << std::endl;

int main(){
   int my_variable=3;
   MY_PRINT( my_variable );
   // I would like to print to console
   // 'my_variable'=3
}
```

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". I've had to say that to you so many times in the past, as well, which is a shame.

Comment: Hi Tomalek, please see response below. It is enough to add '#' character

Comment: Yes, I know what the answer is myself, too. But I am trying to train you, a little late, into writing proper questions.

Comment: Ok. I didn't understand your intent.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Auch... I found the solution.

I should write the macro like this

```
 #define MY_PRINT(x) std::cout << #x"=" << x << std::endl
```

Answer (score 5):

For C++ I use this:

```
#define STR(x) #x << '=' << x

int main()
{
  int i = 1;
  std::string str("hello");
  std::vector<std::string> vec;
  my_class mc;

  ...

  std::cout << STR(i) << std::endl
            << STR(str) << std::endl
            << STR(vec) << std::endl
            << STR(mc) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This way the compiler chooses the streaming operator based on the data type, so you don't need to bother with different macros for each, and it can go to any std::ostream, not just std::cout. Just provide the appropriate streaming operator for your data:

```
std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&);
std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::vector<T>&);
etc
```

But I wish there was a template way to replace the macro, or at least the variable name provided by the #x.